# Tableau Count Distinct when graphed shows chronological last date, when deduplicated, not first

Tags: tableau-api

I'm doing a break fix on a Tableau report visualization that shows the outcomes of clients by client id for a given year by showing a running sum of distinct count of client id or RUNNING_SUM(COUNTD([ID])). The X axis of the visualization is the initial date of contact with the client. Occasionally, due to errors in the data or weird behavior, there are clients that have two initial dates, listed as two separate data rows where the column Initial Date will have different values but they will share an ID.

Currently, the visualization shows such people with their chronological last Initial Date and I need it to dedup such that the visualization shows them as starting from the chronological first Initial Date.

I could create a calculated field for if there are two IDs with multiple non identical Initial Dates then use the first, but I'm not sure how to create a calculated field that can groupby or otherwise check multiple dates per ID.

In Python/psuedo code, it would be something like

```
For ID in IDS:
 if len(groupby.IDS.ID)>1:
    then Initial_Date = min(InitialDate)
```

But I have to do the transformation in Tableau

Comment: Maybe `Initial_Date2 = {FIXED [ID]: MIN(Initial_Date)}`?

Answer (score 0):

Keep everything the same, but create a calculated field named "Initial Contact Date" with the calculation:

```
{FIXED [ID]: MIN(InitialDate)}
```

Then replace the date field on the X axis (Columns) with this date field instead.

That [LOD Expression](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod.htm) loops through all rows given the ID, and returns only the min one.

[image]